# Apache Spark:executor driver lost

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm reading Data with mongo-hadoop connector in to RDD and executing SQL tasks on it.

Spark mode is single-node , running with .jar `spark-submit`

Memory used :`12.9 GB RAM` and `4 GB HDD`

While running a series of tasks, one of the task has failed and this is the information shown there.

> Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5925 in stage 17.0 failed 1
>   times, most recent failure: Lost task 5925.0 in stage 17.0 (TID
>   137504, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver lost)

Why the task failed?

Also the next task in the queue was executed 498 stages and then it was paused.

Comment: ExecutorLostExceptions usually occur when there is a memory problem. Are you running in stand-alone mode? Yarn? Have you looked in the log-files to see which exceptions are being reported?

Comment: I didn't see log files. It is standalone without Yarn. However, after restarting, I didn't face it.

Comment: Ok - problem solved then, I guess ;-) If you encounter it again, have a look at the log files and scan for exceptions being thrown.